# Why is oracle dictionary lying to me?

Tags: oracle, dictionary, constraints

In the documentation for all_constraints table it says that the "owner" column gives us information about "Owner of the constraint definition". But when examining the living example I found that to be false.

`select user from dual; --gives EXAMPLE_USER
create table example_user.example_table(id number);`

Now I will change user to SYS.

`select user from dual --gives SYS
alter table example_user.example_table add constraint ex_constrain check(id > 10);`

Now the best part:

`select owner from all_constraints where constraint_name = 'EX_CONSTRAINT'; 
--gives EXAMPLE_USER and not SYS.`

My question is simple: why?
Tested on: Oracle Database 11g EE 11.2.0.4.0

Comment: What does `INDEX_OWNER` column say ..?

Comment: It says null. What does it have to do with the constraint itself?

Comment: Nothing, as it is a check constraint and there's no index behind it. If you created a primary key constraint, then you'd create index (sharing the same name with the constraint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, SYS is *special*, it owns the database and can do anything.

If you wanted to do the same with another user (for example, SCOTT, and let it try to create constraint for EXAMPLE_USER's table), you'd fail unless privileged user grants SCOTT `ALTER ANY TABLE` system privilege. Doing so, that user will be able to alter *any* table (which belongs to any user), and that includes creating constraints.

If you'd want to create a primary key constraint, that privilege won't be enough - you'll need `CREATE ANY INDEX` privilege as well (as primary key creates index as well).

Just like `CREATE ANY TABLE` system privilege, which allows you to create a table in any other user's schema, but that table will then belong to the schema owner, the same goes for a constraint - yes, you created it *in behalf* of another user, but the constraint is still owned by the table owner, not the creator.

Therefore, dictionary isn't lying, it is you who misunderstood how it goes.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! But then is there any way to check who created the constraint on behalf of other user?

Comment: You're welcome. If there is a way to find *the culprit*, I don't know it. That's why system privileges should be granted very rarely and only for a good reason.